# How to prove that the function $\dfrac{\text{dist}(u,X-A)}{\text{dist}(u,X-A)+\text{dist}(u,B)}$ is locally Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is a Hilbert space and $A,B\subset X$ are closed subsets such that $B\subset A$.

I'm trying to prove that the function $g(u)=\dfrac{\text{dist}(u,X-A)}{\text{dist}(u,X-A)+\text{dist}(u,B)}$ is locally Lipschitz ($X-A $ is the set of all elements $x\in X$ such that $x$ is not in $A$). I've tried some algebraic manipulations using the definition of distance function, ($\text{dist}(u,C)$ is the infimum of the numbers $||u-y|| $ such that $y\in C$), but it was fruitless. I will aprecciate some hints.

Such function appears in the demonstration of the Quantitative deformation lemma given in the book Minimax Theorems by Michel Willem.

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Comment: I think the following reasoning could work: $u\mapsto dist(u,B)$ is Lipschitz, the denominator is bounded from below by $dist(B,X-A)>0$, then the resulting function is a composition of Lipschitz functions.

Comment: @daw What functions are you composing? Because at least in my calculations It did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(u):=dist(u,X-A)$, $g(u):=dist(u,B)$. Then $f$ and $g$ are Lipschitz. In addition, $f(u) + g(u) \ge dist(B,X-A)=:\delta>0$.

Then
$$
\frac{f(u)}{f(u)+g(u)} - 
\frac{f(v)}{f(v)+g(v)} 
= \frac{f(u)(f(v)+g(v))-f(v)(f(u)+g(u))}{(f(u)+g(u))(f(v)+g(v))}
= \frac{f(u)g(v)-f(v)g(u))}{(f(u)+g(u))(f(v)+g(v))}
=\frac{f(u)g(v)-f(v)g(u))}{(f(u)+g(u))(f(v)+g(v))}
=\frac{f(u)(g(v)-g(u))}{{(f(u)+g(u))(f(v)+g(v))}}+\frac{(f(u)-f(v))g(u))}{(f(u)+g(u))(f(v)+g(v))}.
$$
Each summand can be estimated like
$$
\left| \frac{f(u)(g(v)-g(u))}{{(f(u)+g(u))(f(v)+g(v))}} \right|
\le 1\cdot \frac{ |g(v)-g(u)|}{f(v)+g(v)} \le \frac1\delta |g(v)-g(u)|.
$$